# Alertdialog with a custom listview - click event is not triggered

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

My goal is to create an alertdialog displaying a list of choices, each one of them represented by an image and a text. The user is supposed to make a choice in the alertdialog and validate it.
I have decided to build this alertdialog with a custom ListView inside it. So far, no problem but I can’t find a way to do the selection. 
I want to create a click event or check boxes but none of these of options seems to work. The most elegant way for me is the click event on a specific row of the list view and here is my code. For now, if I click, it doesn’t do anything. 
Your help is much appreciated.

```
MainActivity

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
    (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item,null);

        ListView LV = (ListView)row.findViewById(R.id.Listview_card);

        Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        String[] names = res.getStringArray(R.array.image_name);
        int[] images =
    {R.drawable.image01,R.drawable.image02,R.drawable.image03,  
    R.drawable.image04};

        ArrayList<singleRow> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            array_list.add(new singleRow(names[i],images[i]));
        }

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
    array_list);
        LV.setAdapter(adapter);
        LV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> 
    parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "coucou2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                      }
                                  });

        builder.setView(row);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Validate Choice",new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"coucou3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.show();
    }}

activity_main xml
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.replics.customlist.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="49dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="44dp" /
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

CustomAdapter
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<singleRow> array_list;

    CustomAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<singleRow> List_Sent) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.array_list = List_Sent;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View View, ViewGroup Viewgroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
    (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview,Viewgroup,false);

        //find objet in each line
        TextView TV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textview_custo_LV);
        ImageButton IM = 
    (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.image_button_custo_LV);

        //get the position
        singleRow temp_obj = array_list.get(i);

        //set each line
        TV.setText(temp_obj.name);
        IM.setImageResource(temp_obj.image);

        //give the right properties to the image
        IM.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        IM.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        IM.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        //return final line
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return array_list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return array_list.size();
    }

    }

row_item xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="List all images" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Listview_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

singleRow
    public class singleRow {
    String name;
    int image;
    public singleRow(String name, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
         }
    }

custom_listview xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button_custo_LV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/image01" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/textview_custo_LV"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="image01" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please point out your problem 1 by 1, what you've tried and what didn't work, also i made a similar code that you'are trying to achieve maybe it will give you some idea, https://github.com/nooballday/dialog-with-list

Comment: Thanks a lot Achmad for your quick answer.
To sum up, I am successful at displaying an alertdialog with a custom list with a picture and a text for each line. I can display buttons to close the alertdialog.
What I can't do is to identify which line is selected. I want to do this by setting LV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // code to execute when I click on a list line } ) but when I execute, I never reach the section of the code I added.

Also I have looked at your link and it seems your list is a bit simpler. Only text. That would be the main difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue.

What I did is modify each single row of my listview so that each contains a checkbox. 
When clicking on the validate button, I read the user answer and decide whether or not it is a valid answer. 
However, I have now another problem but I am posting a new questions as the 2 issues are not really related.

This is my custom line layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_button_custo_LV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/wonder01" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_custo_LV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choisir" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_custo_LV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Wonder1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my listview layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_Expl_List"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Choose one card: "
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Listview_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

This is my activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.boardgamereplics.customlistforstackflow.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Single Row java class:

```
public class singleRow {
String name;
int image;
boolean ischecked;


public singleRow(String name, int image, boolean ischecked) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.ischecked = ischecked;
}
```

Custom adapter java class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter { //implements View.OnClickListener {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<singleRow> array_list;
//TODO change l'objet singlerow par card et arrange toi pour passer les cartes que tu veux.

CustomAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<singleRow> List_Sent) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.array_list = List_Sent;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View View, ViewGroup Viewgroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_line_model,null);

    //find objet in each line
    TextView TV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textview_custo_LV);
    ImageButton IM = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.image_button_custo_LV);
    CheckBox CB = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_custo_LV);

    //get the position
    singleRow temp_obj = array_list.get(i);

    //set each line
    TV.setText(temp_obj.name);
    IM.setImageResource(temp_obj.image);
    CB.setChecked(false);

    //give the right properties to the image
    IM.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    IM.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    IM.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    //return final line
    return row;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return array_list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return array_list.size();
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1 = null;
    Context ctx = null;
    TextView T_pop1 = null;
    TextView T_pop2 = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder_pop2 = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder_pop1 = null;
    // ListView LV_pop1 = null;
    // ListView LV_pop2 = null;
    Button Validate_btn_pop1 = null;
    Button Validate_btn_pop2 = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ctx = this;
    b1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                  displayAlert();
                              }
                          }
    );

}

public void displayAlert() {
    builder_pop1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

    LayoutInflater inflater_pop1 = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listview_lay_pop1 = inflater_pop1.inflate(R.layout.listview_lay, null);

    //identify objet in second alertdialog
    final ListView LV_pop1 = (ListView) listview_lay_pop1.findViewById(R.id.Listview_card);

    //populate listview
    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    String[] names = res.getStringArray(R.array.wonders_name1);
    int[] images = {R.drawable.wonder01, R.drawable.wonder02, R.drawable.wonder03, R.drawable.wonder04};

    ArrayList<singleRow> array_list_pop1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        array_list_pop1.add(new singleRow(names[i], images[i], false));
    }

    CustomAdapter adapter_pop1 = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), array_list_pop1);
    LV_pop1.setAdapter(adapter_pop1);

    builder_pop1.setView(listview_lay_pop1);
    builder_pop1.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    final AlertDialog dialog_pop1 = builder_pop1.create();

    dialog_pop1.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog_ins_pop1) {
            //Overriding the handler immediately after show is probably a better approach than OnShowListener as described below
            T_pop1 = (TextView) ((AlertDialog) dialog_pop1).findViewById(R.id.Text_Expl_List);
            Validate_btn_pop1 = ((AlertDialog) dialog_pop1).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Validate_btn_pop1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v_pop1) {
                    Integer choice = 0;
                    Integer counter_ischecked = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        CheckBox CBF_pop1 = (CheckBox) LV_pop1.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox_custo_LV);
                        boolean isSelected = CBF_pop1.isChecked();
                        if (isSelected == true) {
                            choice = choice + i;
                            counter_ischecked++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (counter_ischecked == 0) {
                        T_pop1.setText("Choose one card");
                    }
                    if (counter_ischecked == 1) {
                        b1.setText("Success");
                        dialog_pop1.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (counter_ischecked != 0 && counter_ischecked != 1) {
                        T_pop1.setText("Choose only one card");
                    }

                }
            }
            );
        }
    });
    dialog_pop1.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have checkbox inside your list ? the solution is simple

Inside your dialog, list adapter add one more variable in your model class to save if the checkbox is checked

and in your adapter add listener to your checkbox like so

```
 mQuestionCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        modelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        modelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Essentially what it does is modify your current object of your item, whether its check of not, and to get the value is simply loop your current List of models and check if its checked or not via the boolean variable that we made earlier.

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < modelList.size(); i++) { //loop through your data list
            QuestionerKerusakanModel current = modelList.get(i);
            if (current.isChecked()) { //check if the item is checked or not
                tempGejala.add(current); //adding it to new filtered List or modify the object however you want
            }
        }
```

and also you should start using RecyclerView instead of ListView, it has the same principle only better.